# Rewrite rule printout in make file

Tags: makefile

I am currently using a makefile for cocotb, similar to [this](https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/blob/master/examples/mixed_language/tests/Makefile).

That consists of a bunch of variable definitions followed by and

```
include $(shell cocotb-config --makefiles)/Makefile.sim
```

Where the final commands will be executed.

I run it in Visual studio code, the simulator output message format is `(%file,%line|%column)`. I want them to be shown as `(%file:%line:%col)`. I can easily do it piping the output to sed.

```sh
make MODULE=x TESTCASE=y | sed -e 's/,\([0-9]\+\)|\([0-9]\+\)):/:\1:\2):/g'
```

I was expecting to be able to change the make file so that the output will be edited before shown

Something like

```makefile
...
.DEFAULT:
  make -C $PWD -f $(shell cocotb-config --makefiles)/Makefile.sim \
     (all variables/environment) (rule) \
    | sed -e 's/,\([0-9]\+\)|\([0-9]\+\)):/:\1:\2):/g
```

Where "magic rule" would apply the specified rule and pipe its output to sed.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend to not put the main logic of the makefile on its head by forcing an artificial top rule which would then need to be if-elsed with a test on `$(MAKELEVEL)` plus introducing a possibly complicated scheme to shuttle all command line options into the second call. Instead, I'd go for an extension of the command line which calls the simulator (or whatever produces the lines you want to tansform) by appending a simple `$(PRETTY_PRINT_SED_CMD)` which you set globally to your desired `sed` instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example, it seems like the [`.DEFAULT` target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Last-Resort.html) would do what you want:

```
.DEFAULT:
        $(MAKE) -f $$(cocotb-config --makefiles)/Makefile.sim $@ \
            | sed -e 's/,\([0-9]\+\)|\([0-9]\+\)):/:\1:\2):/g
```

### Edit (from the OP)

The default works when the rule is given, e.g. if I invoke `make sim`  instead of `make`. For this I can create a `default-delegate` rule.

More importantly, I have to pass all the variables to the sub make, that can be achieved by using export by itself.

Then, replacing the `include` command but the following snippets, works for the more common cases.

```makefile
export
default-delegate: sim
.DEFAULT:
    $(MAKE) -f $$(cocotb-config --makefiles)/Makefile.sim $@ \
      | sed -e 's/,\([0-9]\+\)|\([0-9]\+\)):/:\1:\2):/g'
```